# Python, splitting strings on middle characters with overlapping matches using regex

Tags: python, regex, split

In Python, I am using regular expressions to retrieve strings from a dictionary which show a specific pattern, such as having some repetitions of characters than a specific character and another repetitive part (e.g. `^(\w{0,2})o(\w{0,2})$`).

This works as expected, but now I'd like to split the string in two substrings (eventually one might be empty) using the central character as delimiter. The issue I am having stems from the possibility of multiple overlapping matches inside a string (e.g. I'd want to use the previous regex to split the string *room* in two different ways, *(r, om)* and *(ro, m)*).

Both `re.search().groups()` and `re.findall()` did not solve this issue, and the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) on the re module seems to point out that overlapping matches would not be returned by the methods.

Here is a snippet showing the undesired behaviour:

```
import re
dictionary = ('room', 'door', 'window', 'desk', 'for')
regex = re.compile('^(\w{0,2})o(\w{0,2})$')
halves = []
for word in dictionary:
    matches = regex.findall(word) 
    if matches:
        halves.append(matches)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer mainly not to leave the question answered in the case someone stumbles here in the future and since I've managed to reach the desired behaviour, albeit probably not in a very pythonic way, this might be useful as a starting point from someone else. Some notes on how improve this answer (i.e. making more "pythonic" or simply more efficient would be very welcomed).

The only way of getting all the possible splits of the words having length in a certain range and a character in certain range of positions, using the characters in the "legal" positions as delimiters, both using the`re` and the new `regex` modules involves using multiple regexes. This snippet allows to create at runtime an appropriate regex knowing the length range of the word, the char to be seek and the range of possible positions of such character.

```
dictionary = ('room', 'roam', 'flow', 'door', 'window', 
              'desk', 'for', 'fo', 'foo', 'of', 'sorrow')
char = 'o'
word_len = (3, 6)
char_pos = (2, 3)
regex_str = '(?=^\w{'+str(word_len[0])+','+str(word_len[1])+'}$)(?=\w{'
             +str(char_pos[0]-1)+','+str(char_pos[1]-1)+'}'+char+')'
halves = []
for word in dictionary:
    matches = re.match(regex_str, word)
    if matches:
        matched_halves = []
        for pos in xrange(char_pos[0]-1, char_pos[1]):
            split_regex_str = '(?<=^\w{'+str(pos)+'})'+char
            split_word =re.split(split_regex_str, word)
            if len(split_word) == 2:
                matched_halves.append(split_word)
        halves.append(matched_halves)
```

The output is:

```
[[['r', 'om'], ['ro', 'm']], [['r', 'am']], [['fl', 'w']], [['d', 'or'], ['do', 'r']], [['f', 'r']], [['f', 'o'], ['fo', '']], [['s', 'rrow']]]
```

At this point I might start considering using a regex just to find the to words to be split and the doing the splitting in 'dumb way' just checking if the characters in the range positions are equal `char`. Anyhow, any remark is *extremely* appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Fixed.

Does a simple while loop work?

What you want is re.search and then loop with a 1 shift:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

```
>>> dictionary = ('room', 'door', 'window', 'desk', 'for')
>>> regex = re.compile('(\w{0,2})o(\w{0,2})')
>>> halves = []
>>> for word in dictionary:
>>>     start = 0
>>>     while start < len(word):
>>>         match = regex.search(word, start)
>>>         if match:
>>>             start = match.start() + 1
>>>             halves.append([match.group(1), match.group(2)])
>>>         else:
>>>            # no matches left
>>>            break

>>> print halves
[['ro', 'm'], ['o', 'm'], ['', 'm'], ['do', 'r'], ['o', 'r'], ['', 'r'], ['nd', 'w'], ['d', 'w'], ['', 'w'], ['f', 'r'], ['', 'r']]
```

Comment: This would actually produce an output similar to the previous one ( which is `[[('ro', 'm')], [('do', 'r')], [('f', 'r')]]`). What I'd want is to split _room_  and _door_ in both the possible ways (i.e. `[[('ro', 'm'), ('r', 'om')], [('do', 'r'), ('d', 'or')], [('f', 'r')]]`)

Comment: Changed it to use search + a while loop to do just that. Uses the re.match.start() function to find the start position of a given match, or just breaks if not found. Sorry about the miscommunication, misread your post.

Comment: This would actually include a lot of unwanted possible splits. What I'd want would actually be _all_ and _only_ the substrings created by the split generated by the previous regex (e.g.  `['o', 'm']` should be regarded as an illegal output, since it does not start from the beginning of the original string _room_). Ideally what I'd want to would be a way to retrieve all the possible matches inside a string, and not only the non overlapping ones.